# Enable SOAP/Client Debian

Tags: php, soap, client

I have a php script that need to use SOAP/Client

So i install the php7.0-soap package, and restart Apache2. But I still have this error message :

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'SOAP/Client.php'
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a missing package error. That looks like you're actually missing a file that your script requires.

Comment: Dear Nathan30, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid frustration. You need to *Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*. http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php `SoapClient` and does not require any `require`.